# Aspx master page in MVC application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, master-pages

I know this is an old topic but i was wondering if a newer more elegant solution exists now. I am currently working with a legacy asp.net application and we are adding an MVC project to it. In order to keep uniformity we have been tasked with using the existing aspx master pages in our new project. This [Article](http://www.eworldui.net/blog/post/2011/01/07/Using-Razor-Pages-with-WebForms-Master-Pages.aspx) poses a viable solution. Has anyone found a newer, elegant, or more efficient way of achieving this goal?

Comment: I just have an equivalent Razor layout for each master page. It works pretty well for the simple applications where I've needed it. Yes, I have to modify both of them if I want to make a change. But it's not too hard.

Comment: I can see how that works. I guess im wondering if anyone has come up with anything newer or more slick since this problem is a few years old. Thanks

Comment: The `slick` fix is to get rid of the webforms parts of the app. ;)

Comment: @ps2goat believe me i wish i had the time and the option to do so. Given the circumstance few things are better than a well executed work around that melds both and keeps consistency.

Comment: I know, I have a similar issue.  But as mason said, try to keep a similar master page and layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looked and looked and honestly could not find any one thing that would allow me to keep the look and functionality of my master page with links and functionality. We have decided to use ASPX pages with iframes that point to MVC pages. Eventually the point will be to eliminate the use of aspx master pages. Thanks everyone for great responses.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are new ways to integrate master pages.

Good approach is to have master page and _layout file that share most of the actual content via partial views/user controls as covered in [Mixing Razor Views in WebForms](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingRazorViewsAndWebFormsMasterPagesWithASPNETMVC3.aspx).